# How do I save the page setup margins in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, margins

I am trying to save the setting for the page margins in Visual Studio 2019. When I open the window it comes up with the default of 1" margin on all sides. I then change them to .5" on all sides and then print my file. When I return to print again after closing the project I have to reset the margins. Is there a way to save my settings?
Thanks for your help.
Alex

Please go to
https://alexbrigden.zenfolio.com/p135920353/hf6acf00a#hf6acf00a for a screenshot of what I am trying to do. Here I have changed the margins and now I would like them to stay as the default. I get to this popup by selecting file/page setup in the top left-hand corner.
Thanks again for your help.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12252/Application-settings-in-VB-NET-2-0-and-Visual-Stud#:~:text=To%20add%20application%20or%20user,Settings%20namespace.

Comment: What's the type of your application? Could you provide some screenshots of your problem here? It will help others reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1):

This was driving me crazy too. It seems like Visual Studio remembers the page setup setting per individual source file.

Install the Visual Studio extension "Remember PageSetup V2". Once you set the page setup, it's remembered. The remembered settings are used anytime you want to print any source file, and the settings persist across Visual Studio sessions. Very useful.